# Either mysqldump or mysql import is failing

Tags: drupal-6, mysql

I'm using mysqldump and mysql import rather basically:

```
Server 1: mysqldump -uuser -ppassword mydb > dump.sql

Server 2: mysqladmin -uuser -ppassword drop mydb
Server 2: mysqladmin -uuser -ppassword create mydb
Server 2: mysql -uuser -ppassword mydb < dump.sql
```

However, on server 2, some database information is missing. No errors are reported during the import. I might add this is a Drupal 6 site.

Any ideas why? I've checked server resources and there is plenty of memory free and the load is ok.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what exactly it is that's missing? It's rather difficult to guess where your data might be hiding without that piece of information.

Comment: Did you compare the 2 databases to check for differences? Maybe collation or something else?

Comment: And don't drop the database and recreate it again for every import, just drop the tables. It will spare you this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Talk about XY questions. Thanks for all your suggestions. It turned out a problem with the APC cache and not Mysql after all. The APC cache needed clearing which was why it was rendering the most bizarre results.